# all occurrences for xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

having trouble getting the text for all occurrences matching a certain class regardless where it occurs..

```
name = chrome_session.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold"]').text
```

current output : Dr. Shyam Sundar Reddy P

Sample html

```
<div><h2 data-qa-id="doctor_name" class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold" data-reactid="543">Dr. Shyam Sundar Reddy P</h2></div>
<div><h2 data-qa-id="doctor_name" class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold" data-reactid="650">Dr. C.H. Umesh Chandra</h2></div>
```

Expecting output as

```
Dr. Shyam Sundar Reddy P,
Dr. C.H. Umesh Chandra
```

and so on

any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Your xpath is valid, the problem is with your software/framework. Wich one you use ? Add it to the tags

Comment: Is this works ? `name = chrome_session.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold"]/text()')`

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: @Pbch , Tip: if you use Selenium, then `xpath-2.0` tag seem to be redundant as Selenium supports XPath 1.0 only

Comment: @Andersson: Not *redundant* -- *contradictory* then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get list of values as below:

```
names = [node.text for node in chrome_session.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold"]')]
```

Note that while XPath `//*[@class="u-title-font u-c-pointer u-bold"]` returns the list of nodes, `find_element_by_xpath()` intend to return you only the first occurence. You need `find_elements_by_xpath()` to get all occurences